# Why is my write quota reached with a simple admin bulk remove?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

This weird case happened twice already in the last 2 days.

I used Datastore Admin to remove all entities, no more than 100, to later re–upload db using `remote_api_shell` but after the request the *Datastore Write Operations* reached the limit:

[image]

This is the first and the only operation I did since last 24h reset.

Also the error is reported in `remote_api_shell` when I try to `put` new entities.

Any advice welcome.

---

### Edit:

Here the models, nothing huge...

```
class Brand(BaseModel):
    '''
    Brand class
    `Marca` in Etax db
    '''
    name = db.StringProperty()
    abbr = db.StringProperty()

    def __repr__(self):
        return ('<Brand {0} instance at {1}>'
                    .format(self.abbr.encode('utf-8'), hex(id(self))))

class Model(BaseModel):
    '''
    Model class
    `Gamma` in Etax db
    '''
    name = db.StringProperty()
    code = db.IntegerProperty()
    brand = db.ReferenceProperty(Brand, collection_name='models')

    def __repr__(self):
        return ('<Model {0} instance at {1}>'
                    .format(self.code, hex(id(self))))

class TrimLevel(BaseModel):
    '''
    Trim Level class
    `Modello` in Etax db
    '''
    name = db.StringProperty()
    etax_code = db.IntegerProperty()
    start_production_date = db.DateProperty()
    end_production_date = db.DateProperty()
    retail_buy_prices = db.ListProperty(int)
    retail_sell_prices = db.ListProperty(int)
    list_prices = db.ListProperty(int)
    model = db.ReferenceProperty(Model, collection_name='trim_levels')
    fuel_supply = db.StringProperty()
    gear_shift = db.StringProperty()
    gear_speeds = db.IntegerProperty()
    doors = db.IntegerProperty()
    seats = db.IntegerProperty()
    kw = db.IntegerProperty()

    def __repr__(self):
        return ('<TrimLevel {0} instance at {1}>'
                    .format(self.etax_code, hex(id(self))))
```

[image]

Comment: How big are your model? how many attributes each model have?

Comment: Do your log files tell you any more?

Comment: I have only 3 models with a bunch of attributes, nothing serious. Data to be removed was less than 600KBytes.

Comment: logs does not show anything but this: `2013-02-14 14:03:16.412 Exception while handling service_name: "datastore_v3" method: "Put" request`

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [billing docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing#Billable_Resource_Unit_Costs), that a high-level delete takes several low-level write operations:

```
Entity Delete (per entity): 2 writes + 2 writes per indexed property value + 1 write per composite index value
```

So if 100 entity deletes used 50k write ops, it means that your every entity had 500 index entries.

This can happen when entity has large list properties or havs a compound index spanning multiple list properties (= exploding index)

Do you have any compound indexes defined? What properties does your entity have?

Comment: How many ints were in `retail_buy_prices`, `retail_sell_prices`, and `list_prices`?

Comment: 7, 9 and 9. Nothing massive... The weird thing is I already used Datastore Admin in past days on the same amount of data without ever going over 2% avter several massive deletes.